# Mosquitto ACL Topic Wildcard at Beginning of Pattern Not Working

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

My acl_file says:

```
user openhab
topic readwrite +/cmnd/POWER2
topic readwrite device-a/cmnd/+
```

The log says:

```
1576575835: Received PUBLISH from openhab (d0, q1, r0, m20, 'device-a/cmnd/POWER2', ... (3 bytes))
1576575838: Denied PUBLISH from openhab (d0, q1, r0, m21, 'device-b/cmnd/POWER2', ... (3 bytes))
```

Why does device-a/ work but not device-b/? Shouldn't the + at the start of the first topic in acl match "device-b"?

Mosquitto debian 1.4.10-3+deb9u4.

Comment: This is working fine for me with mosquitto 1.4.14 (latest version is 1.6.8) can I suggest you upgrade and try again. There are instruction on the download page to override the default debian bundled version.

Answer (score 2):

It was because of a trailing space in the line in the acl file.

https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1539

It works after removing the trailing space.

Comment: ahh, yes. Spaces are valid topic chars